# Can't access attributes on a primitive-typed value (string)

Tags: terraform, azure-functions, apim

I try to whitelist my apim public ips over my azure function :

*apim.tf*

```hcl
data "azurerm_api_management" "main" {
  name                = "my-apim"
  resource_group_name = "my-rg"
}

output "apim_ip" {
  value = data.azurerm_api_management.main.public_ip_addresses
}
```

**terraform output**

```hcl
apim_ip = tolist([
  "1.2.3.4",
])
```

*func.tf*

```hcl
resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "az_func" {
  name                = var.my_func_name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  location            = var.location

  storage_account_name       = azurerm_storage_account.main.name
  storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.main.primary_access_key

  service_plan_id = azurerm_service_plan.azfunc.id

  site_config {
    dynamic "ip_restriction" {
      for_each = data.azurerm_api_management.main.public_ip_addresses
      content {
        ip_address = data.azurerm_api_management.main.public_ip_address_id.value
      }
    }
  }
}
```

On `terraform apply` I keep having the error message :

> Can't access attributes on a primitive-typed value (string).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data.azurerm_api_management.main.public_ip_address_id` is a string, and therefore you cannot cannot access values from it as if it were a `map` or `object` type. I believe you meant to access values on the temporary lambda iterator variable assigned from `data.azurerm_api_management.main.public_ip_addresses`. In that, the usage and syntax would be:

```
ip_address = site_config.value.id
```

to access the `id` value from the current `data.azurerm_api_management.main.public_ip_addresses` attribute.